# Выбор режима чего-либо. Как сделать менее затратный переключатель режимов для игры

Tags: java, android

Допустим, есть игра в которой 2 режима. При одном режиме шарики от стен отскакивают, а при другом не отскакивают. В настройках нужен переключатель режимов. Я представляю это так: В настройках есть логическая переменная. А в коде при выполнении проверяется условие, если переменная Истина, то реализуется один участок кода, если ложь то другой. Но при каждом кадре приходится проверять это условие. Возможен ли такой подход, при котором это условие не проверялось бы так часто?

Вот что еще я представляю: В настройках выставлена Истина. Вхожу в класс реализации игрового процесса и в нем в `onCreate` условие: Если истина, то в определенном месте кода выполнять такой то метод. Но таких возможностей Java вроде не предоставляет.

Comment: смотрите паттерн Стратегия

Comment: Долго что ли условие проверяется?

Comment: Alex78191, ну зачем мне эта проверка условия в каждом кадре игры, если его можно избежать и так правильней

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать классическую реализацию preference. Есть настройки например preferenceFragment, там ваш switchPreference, подписываетет его, или переопределяет onPreferenceChange там где нужно, прописываете свои логику поведения, те вставляете ваш метод/функц. боунсить шарики или нет - например обычным сетом. Это очевидный вариант, но путей много. Можете организовать обычный State pattern, через интерфейс, но суть будет такая же. Можете сделать как вы делали через SharedPreference и bool полем, но тогда в onResume , отлавливать его, тоже стандартный рабочий вариант, но только не на каждый кадр... Удачи.

Comment: Автор не хочет этого делать, написано же

Answer (score 0):

Возможен такой подход: в onCreate делается проверка логической переменной и в зависимости от неё создается, тот или иной класс , или тот или иной объект класса

Comment: Только в onResume, как написано у меня. Иначе вы входите в настройки меняете параметр возвращаетесь и он не работает.

Answer (score 0):

ИграА - шарики отскакивают,
ИграБ - шарики не отскакивают.

что если создать 2 класса играА и играБ (играБ наследуется от играА). В классе играА в методе пририсовка кадра убрать if, и сделать нужно поведение шариков. А в классе ИграБ переопеределить метод прорисовка шариков и сделать так чтобы они отскакивали.

Ну и в самой функции запуска игры проверять значение с настроек и на его основе запускать нужный класс.

p.s. Паттерн Strategy

Comment: Strategy немного иной паттерн, вы его не верно понимаете. Подмена динамически класса в играх, плохая идея, используйте State как я предложил в ответе.

Comment: Shwarz Andrei, я тоже думал о таком подходе, но может не класс подменять, а объект класса. Но почему это плохая идея?

Comment: Идея нормальная только паттерн не тот. Попробую объяснить разницу. Есть класс Game и класс StageState, вот первый подменять плохо в рантайме это ближе к strategy, а второй более чем хорошо, это ближе к State. Это довольно грубо написано, да простит меня старина Боб, но для объяснения самое то